# Access Control Lists in Debian Lenny

Tags: debian, apache-2.2, permissions, access-control-list

So, for my clients to who have sites hosted on my server, I create user accounts, with standard home folders inside /home.

I setup an SSH jail for all the `collective` users, because I really am against using a separate FTP server. Then, I installed ACL and added acl to my `/etc/fstab` — all good.

1. I cd into `/home` and `chmod 700 ./*`.

   - At this point users cannot see into other users home directories (yay), but apache can't see them either (boo)
   - . I ran `setfacl u:www-data:rx ./*`. I also tried individual directories.
   - Now apache can see the sites again, but so can all the users. ACL changed the permissions of the home folders to `750`.

**How do I setup ACL's so that Apache can see the sites hosted in user's home folders AND 2. Users can't see outside their home and into others' files.**

**Edit: more details:**

Output after `chmod -R 700 ./*`

```
sh-3.2# chmod 700 ./*
sh-3.2# ls -l
total 72
drwx------+ 24 austin  austin     4096 Jul 31 06:13 austin
drwx------+  8 jeremy  collective 4096 Aug  3 03:22 jeremy
drwx------+ 12 josh    collective 4096 Jul 26 02:40 josh
drwx------+  8 joyce   collective 4096 Jun 30 06:32 joyce
```

(Not accessible to others users OR apache)

```
setfacl -m u:www-data:rx jeremy
```

(Now accessible to members apache and collective — why collective, too?)

```
sh-3.2# getfacl jeremy 
# file: jeremy
# owner: jeremy
# group: collective
user::rwx
user:www-data:r-x
group::r-x
mask::r-x
other::---
```

**Solution**

Ultimately what I did was:

```
chmod 755 *
setfacl -R -m g::--- *
setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rx *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the mask into "---" ?

Or revoke the group permission with setfacl. chmod and setfacl do not work *too well* together.

Comment: This is starting to make some sense, but I don't quite understand 'masks' and 'effective masks'. Can I not just set permissions to allow only user access and then also allow apache?

Comment: Also, I can't vote up your answer, but I would if I could. I wish my Stack Overflow reputation would carry over.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't stop users seeing "outside their home directories" without a full chroot, because they're always going to be able to see into system directories like `/usr/bin` (because that's how programs get run).  I don't see how the `setfacl` command you gave will produce the results shown; can you give the output of `getfacl` and `ls -l` for a user's home directory in your question?

Comment: Normally that's true but they don't have console access — I'm CHROOT-ing and forcing SFTP. I posted more details. Moreover, I only really care about preventing access to other user's directories.

Comment: It looks like you might be getting bitten by the effective rights mask; I've never hit it before, but it's the only thing that makes any sense.  Not sure how to unset it, the setfacl manpage is being particularly obtuse today.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean — I can't find any simple documentation for ACL's — I assumed it'd be a highly used feature. I hope someone else has encountered it, because it seems like it should be a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

For jailing, newer versions of ssh support the ChrootDirectory option.
For scp only connections, I've used [scponly](http://sublimation.org/scponly/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) successfully in the past.

As for apache seeing the files, you didn't quite get the chmod right. Try something like this (assumes apache uses the apache group):

cd /home

chmod -750 *  # owners can do everything, group members can read, others can do nothing

chgrp -R apache *  # by changing group to apache, apache can now read the files.

Remember, you don't want to add regular users to the apache group.

Comment: 1. I'm already using the ChrootDirectory option.
2. I don't want the user's home directories to be in the apache group.
3. I'm not adding regular users to the apache group.

Answer (score 0):

hayalci's comment that

> chmod and setfacl do not work too well together.

helped a good deal. Instead of using CHMOD to prevent other groups from accessing the data, I used:

```
cd /home
setfacl -m g::0 joeuser # Removes permissions for the owning group.
setfacl -m g:www-data:r joeuser # Adds read permissions for Apache
cd joeuser/joeuser.com/static/
setfacl -m g:www-data:rwx uploads # So apache can write to the uploads directory.
```